# How to update back to the text-box after re-format float into 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get and update the data (float) with two decimal places, for example. I have a text-box which allows user to input float number, I use one directive to convert into 2 decimal places:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data" name="data" smart-float />

app.directive('smartFloat', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        var FLOAT_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;

        if (FLOAT_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('float', true);
          return parseFloat(Math.round(viewValue * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('float', false);
          return undefined;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This directive works okay get 2 decimal places on the model, the thing is I want to update back into the text-box, when user click on `check` button, example:

if user input `1.345` on the text-box, then click check button, the value `1.35` should update back to the text-box:

[image]

Is there any way around?

I tried to trigger `$digest` loop in `checkFn` using `$scope.$digest()` but it does not work out.

The [flunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TjD51R4g0vQxUKdP3nN5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular direcitve code to allow only 2 decimal to be typed into text-box

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhpHlrQPmzoll2RIOGQi?p=preview)**</kbd>

It update the text box value on the fly

**Template Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    <div>
      Data:
      <input type="text" ng-model="obj.data" name="data" smart-float value="obj.value" />
      {{obj.data}}<br />
      <button ng-click="checkFn(form)">Check</button>
      <span ng-show="isError">
        This is not a valid float number!</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Directive Code:**

```
app.directive('smartFloat', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$render = function () {
          var value = ctrl.$viewValue || '';
          elm.val(value);

      }
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        var FLOAT_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;

        if (FLOAT_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('float', true);
          return parseFloat(Math.round(viewValue * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('float', false);
         return undefined;
        }
      });
        elm.bind('keyup', function () {

          scope.$apply(function () {
            console.log(ctrl.$valid)
            if(ctrl.$valid){
              viewValue=ctrl.$viewValue || '';
              ctrl.$setViewValue(parseFloat(Math.round(viewValue * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
              elm.val(ctrl.$viewValue);
            }else{
              ctrl.$viewValue=''
              elm.val('');

            }
          });
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the demo doesn't allow you to change from the value once it is set, for example enter 4 (4.00) and try and change it to 4.01. Every time you backspace it adds a 0.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use `ctrl.$setViewValue()` and `ctrl.$render()`

Change you line

```
  return parseFloat(Math.round(viewValue * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

to

```
var transformedInput = parseFloat(Math.round(viewValue * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
ctrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
ctrl.$render();
return transformedInput;
```

For more info visit [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController)

Comment: I got exception: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`, seems it loops forever