# angularjs: allows only decimals to be typed into a text box

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, angularjs

how to  allows only decimals to be typed into a text box in angularjs: . I have find article only numbers .But is it Something like only for decimals ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishchit14/xh5kV/2/)**</kbd>

**Directive**

```
   .directive('onlyNum', function() {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {

         var keyCode = [8,9,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,110];
          element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
            console.log($.inArray(event.which,keyCode));
            if($.inArray(event.which,keyCode) == -1) {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.onlyNum);
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        });
     };
  });
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="number" only-num>
```

Note : Do not forget include jQuery with angular js

<kbd>**Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishchit14/xh5kV/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write a directive, that checks what user inputs. If he enters anything else than a number - either don't update the input field or remove the wrong character (Not 100% sure which approach is easier).
Using directives should be a bit more memory-conserving than watching your model.

Here is a comprehensive directive tutorial: 
http://www.befundoo.com/university/tutorials/angularjs-directives-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Angular direcitve code to allow 2 decimal place in text-box

Check below URL:

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhpHlrQPmzoll2RIOGQi?p=preview)**</kbd>

[How to update back to the text-box after re-format float into 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716577/how-to-update-back-to-the-text-box-after-re-format-float-into-2-decimal-places/18718349#18718349)

Check my solution in above post